# ajax call returns 500 internal error

Tags: php, ajax, json, internal

i have some $.getJSON() calls which work locally just fine but when i upload the script on live server it just throws 500 internal error , i also have some other ajax calls(not json) where some work and some not..

i tried to go directly to the file where i call the $.getJSON() but i just wont get anything.. not a simple error

ex.

```
        $.getJSON("file.php",
        function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
```

throws 500 internal error..

but this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file2.php",
    data: {
        val: '1'
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

seems to work

inside the file.php i check if its an ajax request and then store some values in an array and then echo it as json_encode($array);

all these work on local machine but not on live server

EDIT: solution was just to remove and add again the files on the server.

Comment: Those are two different urls - first `file` then `file2`. Typo?

Comment: can we see the php code? also, do you send the proper headers?

Comment: @Zirak i was just giving an example to see that the first does not work and throws 500 error and the 2nd work,@passcod it works now , i dont know why , i removed all my files and replaced them on the server,probably there was something wrong with the replacement.

Comment: A 500 internal error means it's a problem on the server, not in the JavaScript.

Comment: Add your Edited Solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: solution was just to remove and add again the files on the server.